# grub2: system restart after menu (nvidia, crypt)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, encryption

I got a ThinkPad T410i and I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Grub is showing up but if I select any Ubuntu boot option the system does a reboot.

My first search brought up to add `nomodeset` because of the nvidia card. This option is already set for recovery mode but that did not help.

The Last message grub shows is `loading initial ramdisk`. I checked path and `hd0,msdos5` looks correct to me.

I used the crypt option for my root, could that be the problem?

Details: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9167402/

Any hints what to do next?

**Update**
I did an second install without windows and got the same problem. So it's not windows.

Since the same Ubuntu is booting from my USB drive it can't be any driver issue, correct?